# Drawing a big commutative diagram in tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to draw a big commutative diagram for my paper. The diagram is quite easy, it looks like a 4 by 8 matrix but the labels of the vertices and those of the arrows are quite large. For this reason the diagram doesn't fit the page space.

I am using the package picture and use "tiny" to make them smaller.

My question is if changing the package is possible to rearrange things so that the diagram can fit in the page?

Otherwise, what should I do? Is any possibility to import the diagram from other editors?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the code

```
{\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=1em,column sep=1em,minimum width=1em]
  {
     T^{xzx\inv}(T^{x}(T^{r}(M\ot N))) & &
     T^{xzx\inv}(T^{xr}(M\ot N)) &   
     T^{xzx\inv}(T^{xrx^{-1}}(T^{x}(M\ot N))) \\%1
    T^{xz}(T^{r}(M\ot N)) & &  & T^{xzx\inv}(T^{xrx^{-1}}(T^{x}(M)\ot T^{x}(N))) \\%2
    T^{xzr} (M\ot N) & & T^{xzrx^{-1}} (T^{x}(M\ot N))&  T^{xzrx^{-1}} (T^{x}(M)\ot T^{x}(N)) \\%3
     T^{x}(T^{zr} (M\ot N) )&  & T^{xr'x^{-1}} (T^{xlx^{-1}}(T^{x}(M\ot N))  & T^{xr'x^{-1}} (T^{xlx^{-1}}(T^{x}(M)\ot T^{x}(N))) \\%4
     T^{x}(T^{r'}(T^{l}(M\ot N)))&  A & T^{xr'x^{-1}}(T^{xl}(M\ot N))  &   T^{xr'x^{-1}}(T^{xlx^{-1}}(T^{x}(M))\ot T^{xlx^{-1}}(T^{x}(N)))\\%5 
    T^{x}(T^{r'}(T^{l}(M)\ot T^{l}(N))) & B & T^{xr'x^{-1}}(T^{x}(T^{l}(M\ot N))) & T^{xr'x^{-1}}(T^{xl}(M)\ot T^{xl} (N))   \\%6
     T^{x}(T^{r'}(M\ot N))) &   T^{xr'x^{-1}}(T^{x}(T^{l}(M)& T^{xr'x^{-1}}(T^{x}(T^{l}(M)\ot T^{x}(T^{l} (N))))\\%7 
     T^{xr'}(M\ot N)& T^{xr'x^{-1}}(T^{x}(M\ot N)) & T^{xr'x^{-1}}(T^{x}(M)\ot T^{x}(N)) \\%8
     };
     \path[-stealth]
     (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$T^{xzx^{-1}}((T^{x,r}_{2})_{M\ot N})$}(m-1-3)%A1horiz
     (m-1-3) edge node [above] {$T^{xzx^{-1}}((T^{xrx^{-1},x}_{2})^{-1}_{M\ot N})$}(m-1-4)
     (m-8-1) edge node [below] {$(T^{xr'x^{-1}, x}_{2})^{-1}_{M\ot N}$}(m-8-2)%A8horiz
      (m-8-2) edge node [below] {$T^{xr'x^{-1}}((T^{x}_{2})^{M, N})$}(m-8-3)
        (m-3-1) edge [dashed] node  [above] {$(T^{xzrx^{-1}, x}_{2})_{M\ot N}$}(m-3-3)%A8horiz
        (m-3-3) edge [dashed] node [above] {$T^{xzrx^{-1}}((T^{x}_{2})^{M, N})$}(m-3-4)
       % (m-4-1) edge [dashed] node  [above] {hello}(m-4-2)%A8horiz
        (m-4-2) edge [dashed] node [above] {}(m-4-3)
       % (m-5-1) edge [dashed] node  [above] {}(m-5-2)%A8horiz
        (m-5-3) edge [dashed] node [above] {}(m-6-4)
        %(m-6-1) edge [dashed] node  [above] {}(m-6-2)%A8horiz
       % (m-7-3) edge [dashed] node  [above] {$\mu^{l}_{M\ot N}$}(m-7-1)%A8horiz
        (m-7-2) edge [dashed] node [above] {}(m-7-3)
      (m-8-2) edge  node [above] {}(m-8-3)
      %%%%% verticals\
       (m-1-1) edge node [left] {$$} (m-2-1)%vertical
       (m-2-1) edge node [left] {$$} (m-3-1)%vertical
       (m-3-1) edge node [left] {$$} (m-4-1)%
       (m-4-1) edge node [left] {$$} (m-5-1)%
       (m-5-1) edge node [left] {$$} (m-6-1)%
     (m-6-1) edge node [left] {$$} (m-7-1)%
     (m-7-1) edge node [left] {$$} (m-8-1)%vertical
     (m-1-3) edge node [left] {$$} (m-2-3)%vertical
       (m-2-3) edge node [left] {$$} (m-3-3)%vertical
       (m-3-3) edge node [left] {$$} (m-4-3)%
       (m-4-3) edge node [left] {$$} (m-5-3)%
       (m-5-3) edge node [left] {$$} (m-6-3)%
     (m-6-3) edge node [left] {$$} (m-7-3)
     (m-7-3) edge node [left] {$$} (m-8-3)
     (m-1-2) edge [dashed] node [left] {$$} (m-3-1)%
        (m-1-3) edge [dashed] node [left] {$$} (m-3-2)
        (m-3-2) edge [dashed] node [left] {$$} (m-4-2)
          (m-4-2) edge [dashed] node [left] {$$} (m-5-2)
          (m-5-2) edge [dashed] node [left] {$$} (m-6-2)
           (m-6-2) edge [dashed] node [left] {$$} (m-7-2)
            (m-7-2) edge [dashed] node [left] {$$} (m-8-2)
            %(m-6-2) edge [dashed] node [left] {$$} (m-7-2)
            ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

not perfect diagram yet

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Can you add the code you're using so that we can play with it? And, if you have some time, please give a look at our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The code doesn't compile; I can guess what `\inv` and `\ot` stand for, but I get `No shape named m-4-2 is known`

Comment: I'd also like if you consider the package `tikz-cd` for drawing commutative diagrams!

Comment: @ egreg It should be m-4-3 instead of m-4-2. The diagram is not perfect I was writing it today but Ingave up once I ve noticed that does not fit the page. The ideea is that the diagram consists of this 8 by 4 matrix with long labeled arrows inside between various terms. Yes, \ot and \inv are shortcuts for otimes and power -1.

Comment: I will write tomorrow the exact diagram and replace the code.  Another option would be to brake it in two smaller diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take your picture and translate is with the [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone)-class.
Something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
%packeges you need for your picture
\begin{document}
%Your picture definition
\end{document}
```

This creates a document with the size of your picture.

Then you could include this image with `\includegraphics`.

---

Remark after your edit:

You may also work with `\includestandalone`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{standalone} 
%other packages
\begin{document}
%your content before the picture
\includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{your-standalone-document}
%your content after the picture
\end{document}
```